# CMake Error at find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS std_msgs roscpp)

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, catkin

I'm using roscpp (ros indigo) for my C++ project.
In my cmake file, i added

```
 find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS std_msgs roscpp)
```

but get following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:
75 (find_package): Could not find a package configuration file provided
by "std_msgs" with any of the following names:

std_msgsConfig.cmake
std_msgs-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "std_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"std_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"std_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you have an issue after you followed the instructions provided in the error message?

Comment: `std_msgs_DIR` is a `CMake` variable. You set that in `cmake-gui` or `ccmake` or via the command line `cmake -D std_msgs_DIR=folder`

Comment: Is `std_msgs` included in the `package.xml` file as a build and/or run dependency?